# Display Symfony's HTTP request as a cURL request

Tags: php, symfony, curl, httpclient

I am trying to troubleshoot a [symfony's HTTP client](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html) request.  How can one display the anticipated request as a cURL request such as the following?  Thank you

```
curl -X 'PUT' \
  'https://example.com/projects/01GPX8HPBQ54SA11JKWPWFESM6/document_acl' \
  -H 'accept: application/ld+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer blaBlaBla' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
  -d '{}'
```

Comment: no built-in way to do this, as far as I know. you could hack the CurlHttpClient for some output, which might make stuff easier, but hacking vendor stuff is dirty.

Comment: @Jakumi  What I am currently doing is a custom wrapper which mostly works, but I am never 100% sure what I am displaying is real.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the [`HttpClientInterface`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html).

```php
$client->request(
            'PUT',
            'https://example.com/projects/01GPX8HPBQ54SA11JKWPWFESM6/document_acl',
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer blaBlaBla',
                    'accept' => 'application/ld+json'
                    ],
                'body' => json_encode()
            ]
        );
```

Comment: Question asks how to export a Symfony HTTP request as Curl command (a de-facto standard for request exchange). You're seemingly answering how to use Symfony client.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).